# Showing full height content from another domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, cross-domain

I'm trying to show the content from [this page](https://clients.sparqxp.com/public/store/574N/default/package/SOL-BF4728A9A0EA4194A4BAB52CC816E7F9) on my website.

I tried using an `iframe`, But I can't set it to the full height of the page As I don't have access to the source website.

Also I tried with PHP, But the content is not added to the website, It's coming from some JSON requests and not sure where some of the content is coming from.

I tried to send some CURL requests to the same API:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://marketplace-packages-api-prod.apigateway.co/marketplace_packages.v1.MarketplacePackages/GetMultiPackages');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"packageIds":["SOL-BF4728A9A0EA4194A4BAB52CC816E7F9"]}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$headers[] = 'Referer: https://clients.sparqxp.com/';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Origin: https://clients.sparqxp.com';
$headers[] = 'Dnt: 1';
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

But I'm not getting the full content of the page.

What to do to get the same full content with the full height of the page?

Comment: Show code with `<iframe>` that tries to be full height.

Comment: Just `<iframe src="https://clients.sparqxp.com/public/store/574N/default/package/SOL-BF4728A9A0EA4194A4BAB52CC816E7F9" height="100%" id="iframe"></iframe>`

Comment: I can't detect when the iframe is loaded to give it the height of the content

Comment: Yeah, you're not setting the correct iframe size. Post your HTML and CSS and an MCVE please.

Answer (score 0):

The website in question is built on Angular which loads a basic web page and then uses JavaScript to then populate the page. Using CURL simply brings back the static web page, before JS has populated it. CURL cannot emulate a browser to the same extent.

The URL you are using within in PHP code, is the URL purely to bring back a JSON response for the Angular application to use and populate the web site accordingly.

Comment: So is there is a way to emulate a browser with PHP, Or a solution?